# Is there any way to open an external video player like MX player when a video is played in flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, video, flutterwebviewplugin

I was building an android application using flutter which has a webview opening a website with videos in it. I was looking for a way to be able to open up such videos in an external player like MX player or VLC when the user tries to play them in the flutter webview. Is it possible to do so? If yes, then can you guys let me know how?

Comment: Have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player#-readme-tab-

Answer (score 0):

You can this package called mx_player

[MX Player](https://pub.dev/packages/mx_player_plugin)